# Password invisible in AlLTER USER statement

Tags: oracle

Is there a way to make to password invisible in ALTER USER statement ? This statement will run in cmd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force the user to change the password in the next user login by expiring the existing password using sysdba.

```
    ALTER USER username password expire;
```

Oracle will ask for new password when the username tries to log-in, hence the new password set will be invisible.

But you cannot make the password field invisible in the Alter statement as oracle wont know it is the password field until you enter it in the command line.

Answer (score 0):

If the SQL script is interactive you can use

SQL> ACCEPT pswd CHAR PROMPT 'Password:  ' HIDE

This creates a SQL parameter "pswd" which you can use in your ALTER USER statement.

If this is not an option - you might also run the script in SILENT mode to suppress any output from the session.